# Junit-Expected MalformedURLException but got UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: java, exception, junit, mockito, malformedurlexception

I have a class ServerConnection.java which have below methods

```
 private String getUrl() throws MalformedURLException {
  // some operations and condition
    URL url = getDNSBasedUrl();
}

public String getDNSBasedUrl() throws MalformedURLException{
if(this.nameSpace==null)
throw new MalformedURLException("undefined namespace");
return this.nodeName + this.nameSpace;
}
```

Test case is written as below

```
@Test(expected = MalformedURLException.class)
public void gctNameSpace_Exception(){
 ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection();
 connection.setNameSpace(null);
 String s = connection.getDNSBasedUrl();
}
```

I am expecting MalformedURLException but getting below error.

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<java.net.MalformedURLException> but was<java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException>
```

Don't want to change exceptions thrown from methods, getUrl() is referenced at many places.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the private method `getUrl()` related to the problem? Which JUnit version are you using? How is the [mockito] tag related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

As your test executes a method that can throw a `MalformedURLException` it is required that the test method either handles it with a try-catch or try-finally or simply declares that exception to be thrown, like

```java
@Test(expected = MalformedURLException.class)
public void gctNameSpace_Exception() throws MalformedURLException {
  ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection();
  connection.setNameSpace();
  String s = connection.getDNSBasedUrl();
}
```

Comment: Tried with above solution, didn't work. Also I am handling exception in other method thats why I am using throws keyword.

Comment: I do not see that you handle `MalformedURLException` in the tested method, that is why you have to declare it in the test method - that you expect it to be thrown doesn't matter for this.

Comment: I have tried with handling MalformedURLException in the tested method with throws key word. Still the result is same with error.

Comment: But did you declare the throws also in the test_ing_ method, that is annotated with `@Test` ?